# How to move all list elements up after removing empty elements

Tags: python, pandas

I am using the yelp dataset to get the hours multiple businesses are open. The time range is put in a list full of dictionaries for each company as shown below.

```
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '8:0-18:30', 'Wednesday': '8:0-18:30', 'Thursday': '8:0-18:30', 'Friday': '8:0-18:30', 'Saturday': '8:0-14:0'}
{'Monday': '8:0-22:0', 'Tuesday': '8:0-22:0', 'Wednesday': '8:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '8:0-22:0', 'Friday': '8:0-23:0', 'Saturday': '8:0-23:0', 'Sunday': '8:0-22:0'}
{'Monday': '7:0-20:0', 'Tuesday': '7:0-20:0', 'Wednesday': '7:0-20:0', 'Thursday': '7:0-20:0', 'Friday': '7:0-21:0', 'Saturday': '7:0-21:0', 'Sunday': '7:0-21:0'}
{'Wednesday': '14:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '16:0-22:0', 'Friday': '12:0-22:0', 'Saturday': '12:0-22:0', 'Sunday': '12:0-18:0'}
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '6:0-22:0', 'Wednesday': '6:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '6:0-22:0', 'Friday': '9:0-0:0', 'Saturday': '9:0-22:0', 'Sunday': '8:0-22:0'}
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '10:0-18:0', 'Wednesday': '10:0-18:0', 'Thursday': '10:0-18:0', 'Friday': '10:0-18:0', 'Saturday': '10:0-18:0', 'Sunday': '12:0-18:0'}
{'Monday': '9:0-17:0', 'Tuesday': '9:0-17:0', 'Wednesday': '9:0-17:0', 'Thursday': '9:0-17:0', 'Friday': '9:0-17:0'}
None
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '6:0-21:0', 'Wednesday': '6:0-21:0', 'Thursday': '6:0-16:0', 'Friday': '6:0-16:0', 'Saturday': '6:0-17:0', 'Sunday': '6:0-21:0'}
```

This goes on for 150,000 elements.

As you can see, one element does not have any information and says "None" instead. I used the dropna() command to clear those. However, it leaves a gap in the list and disrupts a for loop I have that calculates the hours.

Here is an small example to explain what I mean.

The table starts as this

```
index,0
0,0.0
1,1.0
2,3.0
3,NaN
4,4.0
5,5.0.
```

and changes to

```
index,0
0,0.0
1,1.0
2,3.0
4,4.0
5,5.0
```

after using dropna()

As you can see, the table skips from 2 to 4.

In my for loop I made it calculate the total time for each week in a range(1-150000), but since there is no row 8 and other rows, it throws an error and stops the loop.

So...
My question is, how can I run my for loop such that is skips over these non existent rows.

Also, here is my code:

```
df_new = df_hours.dropna()

for i in range(1,150000):

  dc = df_new[i]
  print(dc)
  sum_elapsed = 0
  for _, v in dc.items():
      start, end = v.split('-')
      hhs, mms = (int(v) for v in start.split(':'))
      hhe, mme = (int(v) for v in end.split(':'))
      elapsed = (hhe * 60 + mme) - (hhs * 60 + mms) 
      sum_elapsed += elapsed

  print(sum_elapsed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `df_new[i]` indexes `df_new` along the columns, not the index (as it seems you want). Instead, use `df_new.loc[i]`, which *does* index along the columns. Additionally, you can use a `try`/`except` statement to catch any raised `KeyError` exceptions.

```py
df_new = df_hours.dropna()

for i in range(1,150000):
    try:
        dc = df_new.loc[i]
    except KeyError:
        continue
    ...
```

However, you should just iterate over the `index` of the `DataFrame`, which avoids any `KeyError` exceptions:

```py
df_new = df_hours.dropna()

for i in df_new.index:
    ...
```

Comment: They shouldn't be iterating over *anything* manually, use the built-in functions `.apply`/`.applymap` when iteration is the desired functionality.

Answer (score 3):

Given a list of dict:

```
data = [{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '8:0-18:30', 'Wednesday': '8:0-18:30', 'Thursday': '8:0-18:30', 'Friday': '8:0-18:30', 'Saturday': '8:0-14:0'},
{'Monday': '8:0-22:0', 'Tuesday': '8:0-22:0', 'Wednesday': '8:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '8:0-22:0', 'Friday': '8:0-23:0', 'Saturday': '8:0-23:0', 'Sunday': '8:0-22:0'},
{'Monday': '7:0-20:0', 'Tuesday': '7:0-20:0', 'Wednesday': '7:0-20:0', 'Thursday': '7:0-20:0', 'Friday': '7:0-21:0', 'Saturday': '7:0-21:0', 'Sunday': '7:0-21:0'},
{'Wednesday': '14:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '16:0-22:0', 'Friday': '12:0-22:0', 'Saturday': '12:0-22:0', 'Sunday': '12:0-18:0'},
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '6:0-22:0', 'Wednesday': '6:0-22:0', 'Thursday': '6:0-22:0', 'Friday': '9:0-0:0', 'Saturday': '9:0-22:0', 'Sunday': '8:0-22:0'},
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '10:0-18:0', 'Wednesday': '10:0-18:0', 'Thursday': '10:0-18:0', 'Friday': '10:0-18:0', 'Saturday': '10:0-18:0', 'Sunday': '12:0-18:0'},
{'Monday': '9:0-17:0', 'Tuesday': '9:0-17:0', 'Wednesday': '9:0-17:0', 'Thursday': '9:0-17:0', 'Friday': '9:0-17:0'},
None,
{'Monday': '0:0-0:0', 'Tuesday': '6:0-21:0', 'Wednesday': '6:0-21:0', 'Thursday': '6:0-16:0', 'Friday': '6:0-16:0', 'Saturday': '6:0-17:0', 'Sunday': '6:0-21:0'}]
```

Doing:

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday   Thursday     Friday   Saturday     Sunday
0   0:0-0:0  8:0-18:30  8:0-18:30  8:0-18:30  8:0-18:30   8:0-14:0        NaN
1  8:0-22:0   8:0-22:0   8:0-22:0   8:0-22:0   8:0-23:0   8:0-23:0   8:0-22:0
2  7:0-20:0   7:0-20:0   7:0-20:0   7:0-20:0   7:0-21:0   7:0-21:0   7:0-21:0
3       NaN        NaN  14:0-22:0  16:0-22:0  12:0-22:0  12:0-22:0  12:0-18:0
4   0:0-0:0   6:0-22:0   6:0-22:0   6:0-22:0    9:0-0:0   9:0-22:0   8:0-22:0
5   0:0-0:0  10:0-18:0  10:0-18:0  10:0-18:0  10:0-18:0  10:0-18:0  12:0-18:0
6  9:0-17:0   9:0-17:0   9:0-17:0   9:0-17:0   9:0-17:0        NaN        NaN
7       NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN        NaN
8   0:0-0:0   6:0-21:0   6:0-21:0   6:0-16:0   6:0-16:0   6:0-17:0   6:0-21:0
```

Removing NaN rows, and resetting the index:

```
df = df.dropna(how='all').reset_index(drop=True)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
     Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday   Thursday     Friday   Saturday     Sunday
0   0:0-0:0  8:0-18:30  8:0-18:30  8:0-18:30  8:0-18:30   8:0-14:0        NaN
1  8:0-22:0   8:0-22:0   8:0-22:0   8:0-22:0   8:0-23:0   8:0-23:0   8:0-22:0
2  7:0-20:0   7:0-20:0   7:0-20:0   7:0-20:0   7:0-21:0   7:0-21:0   7:0-21:0
3       NaN        NaN  14:0-22:0  16:0-22:0  12:0-22:0  12:0-22:0  12:0-18:0
4   0:0-0:0   6:0-22:0   6:0-22:0   6:0-22:0    9:0-0:0   9:0-22:0   8:0-22:0
5   0:0-0:0  10:0-18:0  10:0-18:0  10:0-18:0  10:0-18:0  10:0-18:0  12:0-18:0
6  9:0-17:0   9:0-17:0   9:0-17:0   9:0-17:0   9:0-17:0        NaN        NaN
7   0:0-0:0   6:0-21:0   6:0-21:0   6:0-16:0   6:0-16:0   6:0-17:0   6:0-21:0
```

---

Doing your function correctly:

```
def myFunc(v):
    if isinstance(v, str):
        start, end = v.split('-')
        hhs, mms = (int(v) for v in start.split(':'))
        hhe, mme = (int(v) for v in end.split(':'))
        return (hhe * 60 + mme) - (hhs * 60 + mms)
    else:
        return v 

df = df.applymap(myFunc)
```

Output:

```
   Monday  Tuesday  Wednesday  Thursday  Friday  Saturday  Sunday
0     0.0    630.0      630.0     630.0   630.0     360.0     NaN
1   840.0    840.0      840.0     840.0   900.0     900.0   840.0
2   780.0    780.0      780.0     780.0   840.0     840.0   840.0
3     NaN      NaN      480.0     360.0   600.0     600.0   360.0
4     0.0    960.0      960.0     960.0  -540.0     780.0   840.0
5     0.0    480.0      480.0     480.0   480.0     480.0   360.0
6   480.0    480.0      480.0     480.0   480.0       NaN     NaN
7     NaN      NaN        NaN       NaN     NaN       NaN     NaN
8     0.0    900.0      900.0     600.0   600.0     660.0   900.0
```

Total sum:

```
>>> df.sum().sum()
30600.0
```

---

Vectorized(ish), and working with timedelta's instead of re-inventing the wheel:

```
for col in df:
    x = df[col].str.extract('(\d*):(\d*)-(\d*):(\d*)').astype(float)
    h = x.loc[:, ::2].apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='h')
    m = x.loc[:, 1::2].apply(pd.to_timedelta, unit='m')
    x = h + m.values
    df[col] = x[2] - x[0]

>>> df.sum().sum()
Timedelta('21 days 06:00:00')

>>> df.sum().sum().total_seconds() // 60
30600.0

>>> df
           Monday         Tuesday       Wednesday        Thursday            Friday        Saturday          Sunday
0 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 10:30:00 0 days 10:30:00 0 days 10:30:00   0 days 10:30:00 0 days 06:00:00             NaT
1 0 days 14:00:00 0 days 14:00:00 0 days 14:00:00 0 days 14:00:00   0 days 15:00:00 0 days 15:00:00 0 days 14:00:00
2 0 days 13:00:00 0 days 13:00:00 0 days 13:00:00 0 days 13:00:00   0 days 14:00:00 0 days 14:00:00 0 days 14:00:00
3             NaT             NaT 0 days 08:00:00 0 days 06:00:00   0 days 10:00:00 0 days 10:00:00 0 days 06:00:00
4 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 16:00:00 0 days 16:00:00 0 days 16:00:00 -1 days +15:00:00 0 days 13:00:00 0 days 14:00:00
5 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 08:00:00 0 days 08:00:00 0 days 08:00:00   0 days 08:00:00 0 days 08:00:00 0 days 06:00:00
6 0 days 08:00:00 0 days 08:00:00 0 days 08:00:00 0 days 08:00:00   0 days 08:00:00             NaT             NaT
7 0 days 00:00:00 0 days 15:00:00 0 days 15:00:00 0 days 10:00:00   0 days 10:00:00 0 days 11:00:00 0 days 15:00:00
```